# jQuery selecting all divs of a kind and attaching event

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $('#tags').each(function(i,element){

            $(this).on('click',function(){


              $('.otherdiv').toggle();

        });
```

How can i attach the click handler to ALL divs with the id of tags? for some reason this is only targetting the first one

Comment: *"How can i attach the click handler to ALL divs with the id of tags?"* You **can't have** more than one `div` with an `id` of `"tags"`. IDs [must be *unique* in the document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

Answer (score 5):

There is no need for the each, just do:

```
$('.tags').on('click',function(){
    $('.otherdiv').toggle();
});
```

and apply a class of `tags` to each of the divs, you should not have multiple divs with the same id.

This will then apply the on click bindings to all divs with a `tags` class.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have more than one ID.

use classes instead.

```
$(".tags").click(function() {
       $('.otherdiv').toggle();
});
```

attribute the css class to every element you want

Answer (score 0):

IDs are unique. You shouldn't have more than 1 element with any given id.
As noted in other answer, use `class` instead to select multiple elements.